# Changing value of a HTML button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a script with a function that changes the value of a button.
The button is in the same document in the html code.
The problem is that the value of the button wont change.
Can you help me fix it?

Here's the code:

```
function changeCounting(){
    var element = document.getElementById("counting");
    if(element.value == '+')element.value = '-';
    else if(element.value == '-')element.value = '*';
    else if(element.value == '*')element.value = '/';
    else element.value = '+';
}
```

Here's the code for the button in the form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="tal1"></input>
    <input type="button" id="counting" onclick="changeCounting()" value='+'></input>
    <input type="text" id="tal2"></input>
    <input type="button" id="equals" onclick="calc()" value="Enter"></input>
</form>
```

Edit: The problem was that i initiated the script after the HTML code.

Comment: Change it from `.value = <string>` to `.innerHTML = <string>` and it *should* work.

Comment: `<inputs>` don't have closing tags btw

Comment: Works fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lk6qw/. Is your script defined before the HTML?

Comment: If Koerner is correct, it's likely you'd notice an issue in the Developer Console to the effect of "Error: Cannot retrieve 'value' from *undefined*". Keeping the console open to look for JS issues can often help.

Comment: Where am i supposed to define the script? Can i define the script everywhere? You have to be kind to me, i'm pretty new to this :D

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, then here is desired code:

### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="tal1" />
    <input type="button" id="counting" value='+'/>
    <input type="text" id="tal2" />
    <input type="button" id="equals" onclick="calc()" value="Enter"/>
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function(){

    function changeCounting(){
        var element = document.getElementById("counting");
        if(element.value == '+')element.value = '-';
        else if(element.value == '-')element.value = '*';
        else if(element.value == '*')element.value = '/';
        else element.value = '+';
    }

    $('#counting').on('click', changeCounting)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dAJTt/

Answer (score -1):

This code looks more simple and readable. Please check this [working example](http://jsbin.com/ilezob/4/edit)

```
function changeCounting(){
  var operationsMap = {
  '+' : '-',
  '-' : '*',
  '*' : '/',
  '/' : '+'
  };

  var element = document.getElementById('counting');
  element.value = operationsMap[element.value];
}
```

Notes:-

1. Make sure your event binding is done, when element is present in the DOM. If you are using jQuery then you can do the binding in `document.ready()` method. I am saying this because we should not intermix Content(HTML), Presentation(CSS), Behavior(JS). This is considered to be best practice. So I would suggest bind your handlers in javascript.
2. Please validate your HTML. There are many tools online to validate your HTML.

Comment: I will write all my code like this from now on :D it looks beautiful

Answer (score -1):

```
function changeCounting(){
    var element = document.getElementById("counting");
    if (element.value == '+'){ element.value = '-'; }
    else if (element.value == '-'){ element.value = '*'; }
    else if(element.value == '*'){ element.value = '/'; }
    else { element.value = '+'; }
}
```

Comment: It's still same as @WooCash answer. No improvements, nothing extra.

Comment: @blunderboy You are wrong. He ask `"Can you help me fix it?"` so I write working code. I don't know why you minus my answer.

Comment: @WooCaSh I didn't do it. I downvoted on this answer that's why I left comment here.

Comment: @WooCaSh You definitely solved the problem with working example. I just added my answer just because I thought it adds more readability. Thats all :)